# How to show no of notification at the top of a ImageView

Tags: android, notifications

I have 3 unread messages. For this reason, I have to show `3` at the top of a message like this picture:

[image]

How can I do this? PLease help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this repo will help you.
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relative layout to show your icons, than you can put another relative layout(rl2) over message icon with relative margins containing circular imageview and an textView above it, control the visibility of rl2 from activity along with the text of textview,

Suppose,
There is are 3 new messages, set visibility of rl2 visible and set text of the textview to 3, In case there are now new messages, set visibility of rl2 to invisible.